# Java 6.0 Virtual Machine re-caches application on every load

Tags: windows, permissions, java

I have a Java application which is loaded and cached by the JRE and for most users it only needs to cache once unless the application software has changed.

However, I have one computer that caches the entire application every time they load it. It is not the version of the JRE, I have that running on other machines. It also works on this machine if logged in as a local admin, just not as a standard user.

Does anybody have any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: I assume we're talking about a JNLP/Web Start application and not a local one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "caching the application".  Do you mean loading it into memory?  That is how a normal JVM works.  Are you trying to flush heap memory?  Can you provide more detail on what exactly you mean?

Comment: Not quite - the application is downloaded from the server and cached onto disk but if the application hasn't changed then it shouldn't be downloaded every time the application is started.

Nothing to do with how the JVM handles memory once the app is started.

Comment: How are you caching it?  Are you just downloading compiled source from a central server to networked machines to be stored temporarily on their hard disks?

Comment: Essentially yes, it is pulled down and persists on the hard disk so long as there isn't a new version deployed - I believe this is normal JRE behaviour.